# My pictures will not transfer from my Nikon D3200 to my Macbook. It has done it in the past but does not do it now. Do I need a software up date?

Tags: nikon-d3100, sdcard, macbook

I can not get pictures to transfer from my Nikon D3200 to my Mac Book. It has been done in the past but will not work now. Do I need a software up-date?

Comment: Tell us more about your current method of transferring pictures. usb cable? sd slot in the macbook?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try to transfer photos using the card with a card reader, there is no need for any software while transferring with a card.

Just buy a card reader, attach it to USB port, plug in your card and transfer.

Comment: True, but most Mac Books have a SD card reader built in. She can use that.

Comment: did not solve my issue, my MBP does not have an SD-Card Reader built in